# Write an Rx "RetryAfter" extension method

Tags: c#, system.reactive

In the book [IntroToRx](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html) the author suggest to write a "smart" retry for I/O which retry an I/O request, like a network request, after a period of time.

Here is the exact paragraph:

> A useful extension method to add to your own library might be a "Back
>   Off and Retry" method. The teams I have worked with have found such a
>   feature useful when performing I/O, especially network requests. The
>   concept is to try, and on failure wait for a given period of time and
>   then try again. Your version of this method may take into account the
>   type of Exception you want to retry on, as well as the maximum number
>   of times to retry. You may even want to lengthen the to wait period to
>   be less aggressive on each subsequent retry.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to write this method. :(

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The key to this implementation of a back off retry is [deferred observables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229160%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). A deferred observable won't execute its factory until someone subscribes to it. And it will invoke the factory for each subscription, making it ideal for our retry scenario.

Assume we have a method which triggers a network request.

```
public IObservable<WebResponse> SomeApiMethod() { ... }
```

For the purposes of this little snippet, let's define the deferred as `source`

```
var source = Observable.Defer(() => SomeApiMethod());
```

Whenever someone subscribes to source it will invoke SomeApiMethod and launch a new web request. The naive way to retry it whenever it fails would be using the built in Retry operator.

```
source.Retry(4)
```

That wouldn't be very nice to the API though and it's not what you're asking for. We need to delay the launching of requests in between each attempt. One way of doing that is with a [delayed subscription](https://github.com/mono/rx/blob/master/Rx/NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/DelaySubscription.cs).

```
Observable.Defer(() => source.DelaySubscription(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))).Retry(4)
```

That's not ideal since it'll add the delay even on the first request, let's fix that.

```
int attempt = 0;
Observable.Defer(() => { 
   return ((++attempt == 1)  ? source : source.DelaySubscription(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
})
.Retry(4)
.Select(response => ...)
```

Just pausing for a second isn't a very good retry method though so let's change that constant to be a function which receives the retry count and returns an appropriate delay. Exponential back off is easy enough to implement.

```
Func<int, TimeSpan> strategy = n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(n, 2));

((++attempt == 1)  ? source : source.DelaySubscription(strategy(attempt - 1)))
```

We're almost done now, we just need to add a way of specifying for which exceptions we should retry. Let's add a function that given an exception returns whether or not it makes sense to retry, we'll call it retryOnError.

Now we need to write some scary looking code but bear with me.

```
Observable.Defer(() => {
    return ((++attempt == 1)  ? source : source.DelaySubscription(strategy(attempt - 1)))
        .Select(item => new Tuple<bool, WebResponse, Exception>(true, item, null))
        .Catch<Tuple<bool, WebResponse, Exception>, Exception>(e => retryOnError(e)
            ? Observable.Throw<Tuple<bool, WebResponse, Exception>>(e)
            : Observable.Return(new Tuple<bool, WebResponse, Exception>(false, null, e)));
})
.Retry(retryCount)
.SelectMany(t => t.Item1
    ? Observable.Return(t.Item2)
    : Observable.Throw<T>(t.Item3))
```

All of those angle brackets are there to marshal an exception for which we shouldn't retry past the `.Retry()`. We've made the inner observable be an `IObservable<Tuple<bool, WebResponse, Exception>>` where the first bool indicates if we have a response or an exception. If retryOnError indicates that we should retry for a particular exception the inner observable will throw and that will be picked up by the retry. The SelectMany just unwraps our Tuple and makes the resulting observable be `IObservable<WebRequest>` again.

See my [gist with full source and tests](https://gist.github.com/niik/6696449) for the final version. Having this operator allows us to write our retry code quite succinctly

```
Observable.Defer(() => SomApiMethod())
  .RetryWithBackoffStrategy(
     retryCount: 4, 
     retryOnError: e => e is ApiRetryWebException
  )
```

Comment: It looks to me like with this implementation, the source observable is never unsubscribed from. It's a little hard to paste here, but try this, you'll see the interval keep ticking:
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Do(Console.WriteLine).RetryWithBackoffStrategy().Take(1).Subscribe();

Comment: @NiallConnaughton Nice catch! The reason that it didn't unsubscribe from the source had to do with me initially having modelled the method after another internal operator we have, one that produces hot observables. This operator should not do that. I've changed the code to produce cold observables and added a test to verify that it unsubscribes. Thanks!

Comment: Marcus I have tried to use your code, and just had a small question, I tried to ask at Github but that is blocked where I work. So I had to open a new SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189166/rx-back-off-and-retry, could you have a quick look if you have time. Thanks very much

Comment: When using exponential back-off (or basically any back-off-strategy based on `attempt`) it might be unexpected that the back-off-time is never reset. I mean `attempt` is increased on **every** error the observable generates, regardless of how many *good* values there were in between.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe I'm over simplifying the situation, but if we look at the implementation of Retry, it is simply an Observable.Catch over an infinite enumerable of observables:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> RepeatInfinite<T>(T value)
{
    while (true)
        yield return value;
}

public virtual IObservable<TSource> Retry<TSource>(IObservable<TSource> source)
{
    return Observable.Catch<TSource>(QueryLanguage.RepeatInfinite<IObservable<TSource>(source));
}
```

So if we take this approach, we can just add a delay after the first yield.

```
private static IEnumerable<IObservable<TSource>> RepeateInfinite<TSource> (IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan dueTime)
{
    // Don't delay the first time        
    yield return source;

    while (true)
        yield return source.DelaySubscription(dueTime);
    }

public static IObservable<TSource> RetryAfterDelay<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan dueTime)
{
    return RepeateInfinite(source, dueTime).Catch();
}
```

An overload that catches a specific exception with a retry count can be even more concise:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> RetryAfterDelay<TSource, TException>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan dueTime, int count) where TException : Exception
{
    return source.Catch<TSource, TException>(exception =>
    {
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            return Observable.Throw<TSource>(exception);
        }

        return source.DelaySubscription(dueTime).RetryAfterDelay<TSource, TException>(dueTime, --count);
    });
}
```

Note that the overload here is using recursion. On first appearances, it would seem that a StackOverflowException is possible  if count was something like Int32.MaxValue. However, DelaySubscription uses a scheduler to run the subscription action, so stack overflow would not be possible (i.e. using "trampolining"). I guess this isn't really obvious by looking at the code though. We could force a stack overflow by explicitly setting the scheduler in the DelaySubscription overload to Scheduler.Immediate, and passing in TimeSpan.Zero and Int32.MaxValue. We could pass in a non-immediate scheduler to express our intent a little more explicitly, e.g.:

```
return source.DelaySubscription(dueTime, TaskPoolScheduler.Default).RetryAfterDelay<TSource, TException>(dueTime, --count);
```

UPDATE: Added overload to take in a specific scheduler.

```
public static IObservable<TSource> RetryAfterDelay<TSource, TException>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    TimeSpan retryDelay,
    int retryCount,
    IScheduler scheduler) where TException : Exception
{
    return source.Catch<TSource, TException>(
        ex =>
        {
            if (retryCount <= 0)
            {
                return Observable.Throw<TSource>(ex);
            }

            return
                source.DelaySubscription(retryDelay, scheduler)
                    .RetryAfterDelay<TSource, TException>(retryDelay, --retryCount, scheduler);
        });
}
```

Comment: You can also replace the dueTime param with a factory if you wished, as in the above examples.

Comment: I like the first version, a bit less sure about the recursive one. Ideally you'd want to let the user pass in the Scheduler, at which point you can no longer guarantee which one they'll use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Benjol. I agree. I actually use an overload that takes a scheduler (update to code added above). You're right though about the fact that a user could then pass in immediate. One potential solution for this might be throw an exception if Scheduler.Immediate is passed in.

Comment: I took this latest bit and translated it into F# with the help of some other people (bad code and bugs are mine, of course). The code can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404185/how-to-write-a-generic-recursive-extension-method-in-f.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the one I'm using:

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayedRetry<T>(this IObservable<T> src, TimeSpan delay)
{
    Contract.Requires(src != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IObservable<T>>() != null);

    if (delay == TimeSpan.Zero) return src.Retry();
    return src.Catch(Observable.Timer(delay).SelectMany(x => src).Retry());
}
```

Comment: is there any difference between `src.Catch(Observable.Timer(delay).SelectMany(x => src).Retry())` and `src.Catch(src.DelaySubscription(delay).Retry())` ?

Comment: Doesn't look like it.

Comment: I was afraid that I missed something. I think the DelaySubscription is easier to understand than the Observable.Timer + SelectMany. Thanks for sharing your solution which helped me find my own :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Markus' answer I wrote the following:

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    private static IObservable<T> BackOffAndRetry<T>(
        this IObservable<T> source,
        Func<int, TimeSpan> strategy,
        Func<int, Exception, bool> retryOnError,
        int attempt)
    {
        return Observable
            .Defer(() =>
            {
                var delay = attempt == 0 ? TimeSpan.Zero : strategy(attempt);
                var s = delay == TimeSpan.Zero ? source : source.DelaySubscription(delay);

                return s
                    .Catch<T, Exception>(e =>
                    {
                        if (retryOnError(attempt, e))
                        {
                            return source.BackOffAndRetry(strategy, retryOnError, attempt + 1);
                        }
                        return Observable.Throw<T>(e);
                    });
            });
    }

    public static IObservable<T> BackOffAndRetry<T>(
        this IObservable<T> source,
        Func<int, TimeSpan> strategy,
        Func<int, Exception, bool> retryOnError)
    {
        return source.BackOffAndRetry(strategy, retryOnError, 0);
    }
}
```

I like it more because

- it doesn't modify `attempts` but uses recursion.
- It doesn't use `retries` but passes the number of attempts to `retryOnError`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another slightly different implementation I came up with while studying how [Rxx](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Rxx/) does it. So it's largely a cutdown version of Rxx's approach.

The signature is slightly different from Markus' version. You specify a type of Exception to retry on, and the delay strategy takes the exception and the retry count, so you could have longer delays for each successive retry, etc.

I can't guarantee it's bug proof, or the best approach, but it seems to work.

```
public static IObservable<TSource> RetryWithDelay<TSource, TException>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TException, int, TimeSpan> delayFactory, IScheduler scheduler = null)
where TException : Exception
{
    return Observable.Create<TSource>(observer =>
    {
        scheduler = scheduler ?? Scheduler.CurrentThread;
        var disposable = new SerialDisposable();
        int retryCount = 0;

        var scheduleDisposable = scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.Zero,
        self =>
        {
            var subscription = source.Subscribe(
            observer.OnNext,
            ex =>
            {
                var typedException = ex as TException;
                if (typedException != null)
                {
                    var retryDelay = delayFactory(typedException, ++retryCount);
                    self(retryDelay);
                }
                else
                {
                    observer.OnError(ex);
                }
            },
            observer.OnCompleted);

            disposable.Disposable = subscription;
        });

        return new CompositeDisposable(scheduleDisposable, disposable);
    });
}
```

Comment: I found an edge-case in which this impl breaks (mixing Immediate and CurrentThread scheduler): 
int a = 0; Observable.Defer(() => a++ < 1 ?  Observable.Return(a) : Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, Scheduler.CurrentThread).SelectMany(Observable.Return(a)))
.Concat(Observable.Throw<int>(new Exception())).RetryWithDelay<int, Exception>((ex, i) => TimeSpan.Zero, Scheduler.Immediate).Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
A simple fix to support Scheduler.Immediate would be to check whether the subscription value has changed during the Subscribe() call before assigning the serial-disposable.

Comment: Depending on the intended semantics of the RetryWithDelay() function it could make sense to reset the retryCount to 0 in the OnNext handler, e.g. onNext: x => { observer.OnNext(x); retryCount = 0; }.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one I came up with.
Didn't want to concatenate the items of individual retries into one sequence, but emit the source sequence as a whole on each retry - so the operator returns an `IObservable<IObservable<TSource>>`. If this is not desired, it can simply be `Switch()`ed back into one sequence.
(Background: in my use case the source is a hot hot sequence, which I `GroupByUntil`an item appears that closes the group. If this item is lost between two retries, the group is never closed, resulting in a memory leak. Having a sequence of sequences allows for grouping on the inner sequences only (or exception handling or ...).)

```
/// <summary>
/// Repeats <paramref name="source"/> in individual windows, with <paramref name="interval"/> time in between.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<IObservable<TSource>> RetryAfter<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan interval, IScheduler scheduler = null)
{
    if (scheduler == null) scheduler = Scheduler.Default;
    return Observable.Create<IObservable<TSource>>(observer =>
    {
        return scheduler.Schedule(self =>
        {
            observer.OnNext(Observable.Create<TSource>(innerObserver =>
            {
                return source.Subscribe(
                    innerObserver.OnNext,
                    ex => { innerObserver.OnError(ex); scheduler.Schedule(interval, self); },
                    () => { innerObserver.OnCompleted(); scheduler.Schedule(interval, self); });
            }));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: btw my first post on stackoverflow ***