# Rx back off and retry

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

This is based on the code presented in this SO : [Write an Rx "RetryAfter" extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978523/write-an-rx-retryafter-extension-method)

I am using the code by Markus Olsson (evaluation only at the moment), and before anyone asks I have tried to get hold of Markus on Github, but that is blocked where I work, so I felt the only thing I could do was ask here at SO. Sorry about that, if this sits badly with any one.

So I am using the following code, in a small demo which is this:

```cs
class Attempt1
{
    private static bool shouldThrow = true;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Generate().RetryWithBackoffStrategy(3,
               MyRxExtensions.ExponentialBackoff,
            ex =>
            {
                return ex is NullReferenceException;
            }, Scheduler.TaskPool)
            .Subscribe(
                OnNext,
                OnError
            );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnNext(int val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("subscriber value is {0} which was seen on threadId:{1}",
            val, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    private static void OnError(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("subscriber bad {0}, which was seen on threadId:{1}",
            ex.GetType(),
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    static IObservable<int> Generate()
    {
        return Observable.Create<int>(
            o =>
            {
                Scheduler.TaskPool.Schedule(() =>
                {
                    if (shouldThrow)
                    {
                        shouldThrow = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("ON ERROR NullReferenceException");
                        o.OnError(new NullReferenceException("Throwing"));
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Invoked on threadId:{0}",
                        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                    Console.WriteLine("On nexting 1");
                    o.OnNext(1);
                    Console.WriteLine("On nexting 2");
                    o.OnNext(2);
                    Console.WriteLine("On nexting 3");
                    o.OnNext(3);
                    o.OnCompleted();
                    Console.WriteLine("On complete");
                    Console.WriteLine("Finished on threadId:{0}",
                        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                });

                return () => { };
            });
    }
}

public static class MyRxExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An exponential back off strategy which starts with 1 second and then 4, 9, 16...
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Func<int, TimeSpan>
        ExponentialBackoff = n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(n, 2));

    public static IObservable<T> RetryWithBackoffStrategy<T>(
        this IObservable<T> source,
        int retryCount = 3,
        Func<int, TimeSpan> strategy = null,
        Func<Exception, bool> retryOnError = null,
        IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        strategy = strategy ?? MyRxExtensions.ExponentialBackoff;

        int attempt = 0;

        return Observable.Defer(() =>
        {
            return ((++attempt == 1) ? source : source.Delay(strategy(attempt - 1), scheduler))
                .Select(item => new Tuple<bool, T, Exception>(true, item, null))
                .Catch<Tuple<bool, T, Exception>, Exception>(e =>
                    retryOnError(e)
                    ? Observable.Throw<Tuple<bool, T, Exception>>(e)
                    : Observable.Return(new Tuple<bool, T, Exception>(false, default(T), e)));
        })
        .Retry(retryCount)
        .SelectMany(t => t.Item1
            ? Observable.Return(t.Item2)
            : Observable.Throw<T>(t.Item3));
    }
}
```

The code makes sense to me, we try and do an operation if that fails we back off and retry. The exception type that we want to retry can be specified, and we also see that the subscriber only sees the final values once after retry which works (in the demo code above the Exception is only done (OnError'd the first time)).

So generally the code works as expected except for one thing.

If I look at the output the code above produces I get this:

```
ON ERROR NullReferenceException 
Invoked on threadId:10 
On nexting 1
Invoked on threadId:11 
On nexting 1 
On nexting 2 
On nexting 3 
On complete 
Finished on threadId:10 
On nexting 2 
On nexting 3 
On complete 
Finished on threadId:11 
subscriber value is 1 which was seen on threadId:10 
subscriber value is 2 which was seen on threadId:10
subscriber value is 3 which was seen on threadId:10
```

The interesting thing for me here is that the subscriber values all come in one go, I would have expected that when the OnNext within the Generate() method were called that the Subscribers OnNext would write the OnNext'ed value to the Console output.

Could anyone shed any light on why this might be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because you are putting a `Delay` on the result stream. (The value for n passed to `ExponentialBackoff` on the second iteration is 1, giving a delay of 1 second.)

`Delay` operates on source, *but the source proceeds as normal.* `Delay` schedules the results it receives to be emitted after the specified duration. So the subscriber is getting the results after the logic of Generate has run to completion.

If you think about it this is how `Delay` must be - otherwise `Delay` would be able to somehow interfere with upstream operators!

It is possible to interfere with upstream operators (without throwing exceptions), by being a slow consumer. But that would certainly be a very bad way for a simple `Delay` to behave.

I don't think the `Delay` is what you intend here - because `Delay` doesn't delay it's subscription. If you use `DelaySubscription` instead, you'll get what you're after I think. *This is what's used in the linked question too.*

Your question provides a great illustration of the difference between `Delay` and `DelaySubscription`! It's worth thinking about `Defer` in here too.

The distinction between these three is subtle but significant, so let's summarize all three:

- `Delay` - Calls target operator immediately to get an `IObservable`, on its `Subscribe` calls `Subscribe` on target immediately, schedules events for delivery after specified delay on the specified `Scheduler`.
- `DelaySubscription` - Calls target operator immediately to get an `IObservable`. On its `Subscribe` schedules `Subscribe` on target for execution after specified delay on the specified `Scheduler`.
- `Defer` - Has no target operator. On `Subscribe` runs provided factory function to get target `IObservable` and immediately calls `Subscribe`. There's no delay added, hence no `Scheduler` to specify.

Comment: James I don't seem to see the DelaySubscription extension method. I am using .NET 4.0, and using rx version : 1.0.2856.104. The Delay extension method that I use is the one from System.Reactive.dll (1.0.2856.104) that I have referenced. But I do not see a DelaySubscription method? Any ideas, would love to confirm your answer

Comment: James, So i just grabbed latest Rx code from NuGet (where there is a DelaySubscription) and that did indeed work. Sadly I can't upgrade the solution. So I guess I will have to look at it, and see what I need to do to bring in that Extension method. Sound like a good approach? Anyway excellent spot thanks for that

Comment: James, Had a look at rx 2 code, quite a bit of difference sadly. Have to have a think about this one, unless you can think of nice way to add that missing functionality?

Comment: Here is a very quick & dirty `DelaySubscription` implementation:  `IObservable<T> DelaySubscription<T> (this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan delay) { return Observable.Timer(delay).SelectMany(_ => source); }`

Comment: Cool Brendan, Its clear to me now I have a bit more learning to do with RX. Thanks very much

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else that happens upon this post, it was indeed fixed by suggestions made by James World, and Brandon (thanks chaps).

Here is full working code

```cs
class Attempt1
{
    private static bool shouldThrow = true;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Generate().RetryWithBackoffStrategy(3, MyRxExtensions.ExponentialBackoff,
            ex =>
            {
                return ex is NullReferenceException;
            }, Scheduler.TaskPool)
            .Subscribe(
                OnNext,
                OnError
            );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnNext(int val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("subscriber value is {0} which was seen on threadId:{1}", 
            val, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    private static void OnError(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("subscriber bad {0}, which was seen on threadId:{1}", 
            ex.GetType(),
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    static IObservable<int> Generate()
    {
        return Observable.Create<int>(
            o =>
            {
                Scheduler.TaskPool.Schedule(() =>
                    {
                        if (shouldThrow)
                        {
                            shouldThrow = false;
                            Console.WriteLine("ON ERROR NullReferenceException");
                            o.OnError(new NullReferenceException("Throwing"));
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Invoked on threadId:{0}", 
                            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                        Console.WriteLine("On nexting 1");
                        o.OnNext(1);
                        Console.WriteLine("On nexting 2");
                        o.OnNext(2);
                        Console.WriteLine("On nexting 3");
                        o.OnNext(3);
                        o.OnCompleted();
                        Console.WriteLine("On complete");
                        Console.WriteLine("Finished on threadId:{0}", 
                            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    });

                return () => { };
            });
    }
}

public static class MyRxExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An exponential back off strategy which starts with 1 second and then 4, 9, 16...
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Func<int, TimeSpan> ExponentialBackoff = n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(n, 2));

    public static IObservable<T> RetryWithBackoffStrategy<T>(
        this IObservable<T> source,
        int retryCount = 3,
        Func<int, TimeSpan> strategy = null,
        Func<Exception, bool> retryOnError = null,
        IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        strategy = strategy ?? MyRxExtensions.ExponentialBackoff;

        int attempt = 0;

        return Observable.Defer(() =>
        {
            return ((++attempt == 1) ? source : source.DelaySubscription(strategy(attempt - 1), scheduler))
                .Select(item => new Tuple<bool, T, Exception>(true, item, null))
                .Catch<Tuple<bool, T, Exception>, Exception>(e =>
                    retryOnError(e)
                    ? Observable.Throw<Tuple<bool, T, Exception>>(e)
                    : Observable.Return(new Tuple<bool, T, Exception>(false, default(T), e)));
        })
        .Retry(retryCount)
        .SelectMany(t => t.Item1
            ? Observable.Return(t.Item2)
            : Observable.Throw<T>(t.Item3));
    }

    public static IObservable<T> DelaySubscription<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
        TimeSpan delay, IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        if (scheduler == null)
        {
            return Observable.Timer(delay).SelectMany(_ => source);
        }
        return Observable.Timer(delay, scheduler).SelectMany(_ => source);
    }
}
```

Which produces the desired output of

```
ON ERROR NullReferenceException
Invoked on threadId:11
On nexting 1
On nexting 2
On nexting 3
On complete
Finished on threadId:11
Invoked on threadId:11
On nexting 1
subscriber value is 1 which was seen on threadId:11
On nexting 2
subscriber value is 2 which was seen on threadId:11
On nexting 3
subscriber value is 3 which was seen on threadId:11
On complete
Finished on threadId:11
```

Comment: In case anyone is trying to see relevant differences between this code and and code in the question, here they are: `source.DelaySubscription` instead of `source.Delay`, and at the end an implementation of `DelaySubscription` (with an extra a `IScheduler` parameter compared to @Brandon's suggestion). The rest is whitespace change.