# Use Rx Start, Retry, Delay, Wait for synchronous file delete retry

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I need to delete a file and some other process in the application blocks it. As a workaround I decided to try several times with an interval. Is it correct approach:

```
Observable.Start(() => File.Delete(path)).Retry(2)
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Wait();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This won't work the way you want. There are three problems:

- Delay doesn't work how you think - it delays passing on the events, but the source still runs immediately.
- You are issuing the `Retry` before the `Delay`
- You need to use `Defer` to create a factory because `Start` will only call the embedded function once on evaluation.

Have a look at this answer for more detail on `Delay` and why `DelaySubscription` is better: [Rx back off and retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189166/rx-back-off-and-retry).

This answer has a good implementation of a back-off retry: [Write an Rx "RetryAfter" extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978523/write-an-rx-retryafter-extension-method?lq=1)

A simple fix for your code could be this, which catches the exception and rethrows it after a delay - but there's no delay if it works:

```
Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(() => File.Delete(path)))
   .Catch((Exception ex) =>
      Observable.Throw<Unit>(ex)
      .DelaySubscription(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)))
   .Retry(2)
   .Wait();
```

Do have a look at the second link above for a  fuller and better implementation though.

I kept the code above simple to make the point and isn't perfect - it always delays the exception for example.

You really want to have the `DelaySubscription` on the action and have it's delay time be dynamically calculated depending on the number of retries, which is what the linked implementation will do.

Comment: This looks broken. Shouldn't we be using `Observable.Defer`? `File.Delete` is only being called a single time in this implementation, which means there's no use in retrying since the Exception is memoized. No?

Comment: Thanks Christopher. Schoolboy error fixed... :) I think I just reminded someone else of that yesterday as well! Doh!

Comment: But that Catch/throw/delay combo is really clever, though. I'm totally gonna use that.