# Polly Retry with RX Observable.Interval

Tags: system.reactive, polly

I'm new to Polly and I'm trying to apply the Retry policy, so that I can have it manually handling the retry connection in case of IBMMQ connection issue.

Please, consider the following code:

```
 public class ReconnectException : Exception
{

}

public class QueueMonitor : IObservable<Message>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly MQQueue mqQueue;
    private readonly MQQueueManager queueManager;
    private readonly string queueName;
    private IDisposable timer;
    private readonly object lockObj = new object();
    private bool isChecking;
    private readonly TimeSpan checkingFrequency;
    private readonly List<IObserver<Message>> observers;
    private TimeSpan reconnectInterval;

    private readonly IScheduler scheduler;

    private readonly int maxReconnectCount;

    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogProvider.For<AonQueueManager>();


    private readonly Policy pollyPolicy;

    public QueueMonitor(IConfiguration configuration, string queueName, IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        this.queueManager = QueueFactory.GetIstance(configuration);
        this.queueName = queueName;
        this.scheduler = scheduler ?? Scheduler.Default;
        checkingFrequency = configuration.GetValue("checkingFrequency", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        reconnectInterval = configuration.GetValue("reconnectInterval", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        maxReconnectCount = configuration.GetValue("maxReconnectCount", 3);
        observers = new List<IObserver<Message>>();

        pollyPolicy = Policy.Handle<ReconnectException>().WaitAndRetry(maxReconnectCount, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        mqQueue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName,
            MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF // open queue for input
            + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING); // but not if MQM stopping

    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var x = pollyPolicy.ExecuteAndCapture(CreateTimer);
    }

    private void CreateTimer()
    {

        Logger.DebugFormat("Repeating timer started, checking frequency: {checkingFrequency}", checkingFrequency);
        timer = Observable.Interval(checkingFrequency, scheduler).Subscribe(_ =>
 {
   lock (lockObj)
   {
     if (isChecking) return;

     Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, () => "Listening on queues for new messages");
     isChecking = true;

     var mqMsg = new MQMessage();
     var mqGetMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions { WaitInterval = checkingFrequency.Milliseconds };

     // 15 second limit for waiting
     mqGetMsgOpts.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING |
                  MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;
     try
     {
         mqQueue.Get(mqMsg, mqGetMsgOpts);
         if (mqMsg.Format.CompareTo(MQC.MQFMT_STRING) == 0)
         {
             var text = mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength);

             Logger.Debug($"Message received : [{text}]");

             Message message = new Message { Content = text };
             foreach (var observer in observers)
                 observer.OnNext(message);
         }
         else
         {
             Logger.Warn("Non-text message");
         }
     }
     catch (MQException ex)
     {
         if (ex.Message == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE.ToString())
         {
             Logger.Trace("No messages available");
             //nothing to do, emtpy queue
         }
         else if (ex.Message == MQC.MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN.ToString())
         {
             Logger.ErrorException("MQ Exception, trying to recconect", ex);

             throw new ReconnectException();
         }
     }
     finally
     {
         isChecking = false;
     }
 }
});
    }


    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Message> observer)
    {
        if (!observers.Contains(observer))
            observers.Add(observer);

        return new Unsubscriber(observers, observer);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ((IDisposable)mqQueue)?.Dispose();
        ((IDisposable)queueManager)?.Dispose();

        timer?.Dispose();
    }
}

public class Unsubscriber : IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<IObserver<Message>> observers;
    private readonly IObserver<Message> observer;

    public Unsubscriber(List<IObserver<Message>> observers, IObserver<Message> observer)
    {
        this.observers = observers;
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (observer != null) observers.Remove(observer);
    }
}
```

The problem I've is that when an exception is thrown inside the lamda ( `throw new ReconnectException();`), Polly doesn't catch it (and I understand why, since it's on another thread) and the application quits since it's on a different thread.

This code is a part of a library,so I don't know that if in every project the Global exceptions are correctly handed.

How do I get it "catched" by the Polly's code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are wanting to use Polly to catch exceptions thrown outwards from the delegate scheduled by the Rx timer, then Polly cannot do that with the approach shown afaik - Rx schedules that work on a completely separate thread (as you say) at a later time. Governing Rx's handling of erroring observables is probably best done with Rx's in-built error handling constructs, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189166/rx-back-off-and-retry . It might be possible to write a custom Rx scheduler to encapsulate Polly and bring Polly into it, but I would try Rx's in built facilities first.

Answer (score 1):

The code posted in the question applies the policy only to the act of creating the timer (the execution of `CreateTimer()`), not to the code executed *by* the timer (the lambda inside the `.(Subscribe(_ => { })` call).

This is the same as the behaviour if the call to `CreateTimer()` was surrounded by a `try { } catch { }`. The `catch` would only cover the act of executing the `CreateTimer()` method, the creation of the timer.

---

For the Polly policy to govern exceptions thrown within the lambda, it needs to be applied within the lambda, to the relevant block/group of statements which are expected to throw the exception.

For example, you might code:

```
pollyPolicy.ExecuteAndCapture(() => mqQueue.Get(mqMsg, mqGetMsgOpts));
```

(with a policy configured to govern the particular `MQException`/s you want to handle).

Or you can apply the policy to a wider group of statements - just as with a `try { }` clause.

```
pollyPolicy.ExecuteAndCapture(() => 
{
    // ...
    mqQueue.Get(mqMsg, mqGetMsgOpts));
    // ...
}
```