# Subscribe to Observable.Retry() doesn't return until it completes?

Tags: system.reactive

I expect `IObservable.Subscribe` to be asynchronous: whatever happens inside, I would like my subscription back.

But `Retry` seems to have a different semantic:

```
var retry = Observable.Throw(new Exception(), 0).Retry();
Console.WriteLine("got here");
var subscription = retry.Subscribe();
Console.WriteLine("didn't get here, ever");
```

There is clearly something I don't understand here. I guess using Retry with no parameters can't be used very often, or it should be used for something that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't anything to do with `Retry` - it's `Observable.Throw` because it defaults to scheduling its `OnError` on the immediate scheduler. Change your first line to this and you are golden:

```
var retry = Observable.Throw<int>(new Exception(), Scheduler.Default).Retry();
```

In general Rx tries to use the most immediate scheduler it can. `Scheduler.Default` will use the current platform's preferred scheduler that introduces concurrency.

`Retry` will initially subscribe on the current thread (which is fine) and then subscribe for each retry on whatever thread `Throw` terminates on.

EDIT

Although the fix above works - it's probably not the best way. It's actually good that `Throw` and `Retry` try to use the immediate scheduler as this is the most computationally efficient way. The code above will cause *every* iteration of `Throw` to run on a different thread.

A better and more idiomatic Rx solution would be to edit the third line instead:

```
var subscription = retry.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default).Subscribe();
```

This causes only the initial subscription to `Retry` to happen asynchronously on a different Thread - and the rest of the processing will stay on that one thread.

Comment: Gngngn. I seem to have a gift for using the right things the wrong way :(

Comment: Just out of curiosity (I haven't had the time to try yet), what could be causing the Retry on my other question to be on the 'wrong' thread?

Comment: It's not just you honest, Rx is a major paradigm shift. I bashed my head against the wall for a while too! Eventually, your brain gets wired up right and it gets easier.

Comment: Added advice regarding SubscribeOn