# How to use UniRx Observable.Timeout set a timeout?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reactivex

I'm attempt use `observable.Timeout` set a timeout but result is beyond my expect.
Code like this:

```
public class ObservableTest : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        var subj = new Subject<int> ();
        new System.Threading.Thread (() => {
            Debug.Log("thread id - " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            var i = 0;
            while(i < 10) {
                i += 1;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(i*1000 );
                subj.OnNext(i);
            }
        }).Start();


        var timeout = subj.Timeout (System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds (4));
        timeout.Subscribe (x => Debug.Log("x - " + x), ex => Debug.LogError(ex), () => Debug.Log("completed"));
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
x - 1
x - 2
...
x - 10
```

Why not interrupt before `x - 5`?How to set a timeout to a observable?

### UPDATE

Sometime output interrupted at `x - 8` I don't know how does it works really.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know why it's continue to work. But You are increasing sleep with each step. So it should interrupt at x - 3

Comment: @ntohl. I know the reason just now.If lose focus Unity editor,when you Running, the Main Thread will hang-up...So the code will not work at all but If you refocus to Unity it will calculate again, `x - 8` maybe activity at the time, further more, a timeout occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the problem. Used Spy() extension from this post >
[How can I see what my reactive extensions query is doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220755/how-can-i-see-what-my-reactive-extensions-query-is-doing)

The problem might be the Thread of the caller isn't handled correctly. It works for me. Disconnects after x - 2.

```
var subj = new Subject<int>();
new Thread(() => {
    Console.WriteLine("thread id - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 4)
    {
        i += 1;
        Thread.Sleep(i * 1000);
        subj.OnNext(i);
    }
    subj.OnCompleted();
}).Start();

//var timeout = subj.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
var timeout = subj.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
IDisposable disp = timeout.Spy().Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine("x - " + x), ex => Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message), () => Debug.WriteLine("completed"));
// That might be missing.
Thread.CurrentThread.Join(10500);
disp.Dispose();
```

output

```
Debug Trace:
IObservable: Observable obtained on Thread: 14, 03:05:24.28
IObservable: Subscribed to on Thread: 14, 03:05:24.289
IObservable: Subscription completed. 03:05:24.296
IObservable: OnNext(1) on Thread: 17, 03:05:25.258 //<- i = 1. One sec wait.
x - 1
IObservable: OnNext(2) on Thread: 17, 03:05:27.261 //<- i = 2. Two sec wait. It's correct.
x - 2
IObservable: OnError(System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.) on Thread: 13, 03:05:29.264 //<- i = 3. Two sec timeout comes into play. Correct. Next step would need 3 sec to finish.
The operation has timed out.
IObservable: Cleaned up on Thread: 13, 03:05:29.266
```

I had a different output, which is also correct

```
Debug Trace:
IObservable: Observable obtained on Thread: 14, 03:20:17.714
IObservable: Subscribed to on Thread: 14, 03:20:17.723
IObservable: Subscription completed. 03:20:17.73
IObservable: OnNext(1) on Thread: 17, 03:20:18.693 //<- 1 sec passed since subscription. correct
x - 1
IObservable: OnError(System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.) on Thread: 12, 03:20:20.698 //<- 2 sec passed, and that was the timeout. There was a race between timeout and OnNext(2). Timeout win. Correct.
The operation has timed out.
IObservable: Cleaned up on Thread: 12, 03:20:20.7
```

Comment: UniRx version seems not Spy method >.<

Comment: The output is very helpful.Stack trace is less use at Thread pool