# In RxJava, how to retry/resume on error, instead of completing the observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

What I want to achieve is:

- monitor preferences for a certain change
- when a change is detected, start new network call using the new value
- transform result
- display result in UI

I know when the change happens, now I presume I need to call onNext on a Subject. This should then trigger a Rx chain, and in the end I can update the UI.

```
mViewPeriodSubject = PublishSubject.create();

mAdapterObservable =
    mViewPeriodSubject
        .flatMap(period -> MyRetrofitAPI.getService().fetchData(period)) // this might fail
        .flatMap(Observable::from)
        .map(MyItem::modifyItem)
        .toList()
        .map(obj -> new MyAdapter(obj));


mViewPeriodSubject.onNext("week"); // this one starts the chain
mViewPeriodSubject.onNext("year"); // this one does not
```

But in the case of the network call failing, the observable errors, and calling onNext() does not result in another network call.

So my question is, how should I handle this? How can I keep the Observable intact so I can just throw another value at it? I can imagine for example a simple retry button that just wants to ignore the fact that an error occurred.

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling), i'm guessing solution 3 or 4 applies (swallow the error and restart), using one of the [error handling operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators) might help, namely [retry or retryWhen](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html).

Comment: There are also a few complete examples for `retryWhen` here on SO.

Comment: @david.mihola Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978523/write-an-rx-retryafter-extension-method (wrong language thou, that's C#).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to deal error with your `mViewPeriodSubject` but instead, deal with errors on your retrofit Observable. This retrofit Observable won't resume, but at least, it won't affect your "main" Observable.

```
mAdapterObservable =
mViewPeriodSubject
    .flatMap(period -> MyRetrofitAPI.getService().fetchData(period).onErrorResumeNext(e -> Observable.empty()) // this might fail
    .flatMap(Observable::from)
    .map(MyItem::modifyItem)
    .toList()
    .map(obj -> new MyAdapter(obj));
```

Comment: This solution works for me. And it has taught me a little bit more about RxJva. Cheers!