# RxJava's .debounce() interfering with my Observable's threads and error handling

Tags: android, multithreading, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I want to make a standard search in my Android app, where I type in an `EditText`, wait a bit until the user is done typing, and fire up a network request using Retrofit :

```
// make observable out of EditText
Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> textObs = WidgetObservable.text(searchText);

mSearchResultSubscription =
    textObs

        // wait until user has not typed for 350 milliseconds
        .debounce(350, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

        // get the string the user typed
        .map(OnTextChangeEvent::text)
        .map(CharSequence::toString)

        // start a new observable (from Retrofit)
        .flatMap(
            q ->
                // try network call and return my data
                MyRetrofitAPI.getService().search(q)

                    // if this fails, just return empty observable
                    .onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
                        Log.e("Error from retrofit: " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
                        return Observable.empty();
                    })

        )

        // if all is well, show the contents on the screen somehow
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(a -> {
                mAdapter.setItems(a);
            }
            , error -> {
                Log.e("Also error in outer observable: " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        );
```

Now, I have a testserver that takes the retrofit call and returns a list. When I type 'crash' the server executes some invalid code and errors, returning http status code 500, and some error html. So, the retrofit call fails.

I would think the outer Observable chain should not be effected by this. See my previous question: [In RxJava, how to retry/resume on error, instead of completing the observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246656/in-rxjava-how-to-retry-resume-on-error-instead-of-completing-the-observable)

But, the outer Observable also errors, causing the chain to terminate. The error is:
`The current thread must have a looper!`

Strange. Now I try without the `.debounce()` and the same thing happens, server has an internal error, but the outer Observable does **not** error.

So what is it about `.debounce()` that it does to threads that is causing this behaviour? And how can I work around it?

Answer (score 8):

Adding to [pturner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31434986/1473844), the Scheduler can be passed as

`.debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

This will cause the observer to work on the Main thread (UI thread) of Android, and will prevent Observer from throwing error.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the issue may be with debounce creating a new thread for the code to execute, from the [docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html#collapseRxJava):

> This variant operates by default on the computation Scheduler, but you can optionally pass in a Scheduler of your choosing as a third parameter.

You might need to pass in an Android scheduler with a background Looper which would solve the error (in theory, unfortunately can't run your stuff right now without the server).

Comment: I think I tried all variations.. no success, unfortunately. I think I might ask on the RxJava/RxAndroid issue trackers

Comment: @xorgate did you get any response? I'm having the same issue. best regards

Comment: @cesarferreira actually I did not ask. I did however remove the .debounce() but I'm not too happy about it...

Comment: I also did that... but it's not cool to let the search happen every stroke that is typed...