# Merged observable sequence doesn't retry on error

Tags: c#, .net, exception, system.reactive

**Info:**

The purpose of the method is to get a secret from a stream, get a uri from a stream. Then hit the uri with the secret and some additional parameters `type` and `name` to obtain some data.

`Secrets.GetSecret()` is an `IObservable<string>` and `Urls.GetHostUrl()` is an `IObservable<Uri>`

**Problem**

The problem I am having is that if the `dataFetcher.GetFromUrl` call throws an exception then the observable terminates. The `RetryAfterDelay` extension method doesn't seem to be working at all.

What I want to be able to do is to be able to catch and log an exception but ideally not have the observable terminate. Or if it has to terminate then to re-subscribe to the original streams, so it behaves as if it has logged/swallowed the exception.

The reason for this is that the network / host isn't the most stable and so sometimes it can error.

**Method**

```
private IObservable<string> GetFromHostUrl(string type, string name, int retryTime)
{
    return Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryTime), schedulerProvider.Default).StartWith(-1L)
        .CombineLatest(Observable.Defer(() => Secrets.GetSecret()),
                                              Urls.GetHostUrl(),
                                              (_, secret, hostUrl) => dataFetcher.GetFromUrl(hostUrl, type, name, secret).Result)
        .Do(s =>
                {
                    // log success
                },
                e =>
                {
                    // log failure
                })
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .RetryAfterDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryTime), schedulerProvider.Default)
        .Replay(1)
        .RefCount();
}
```

**Extension Methods**

```
// c/o: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978523/write-an-rx-retryafter-extension-method
public static class ExtensionMethods
{

    private static IEnumerable<IObservable<TSource>> RepeateInfinite<TSource>(IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan dueTime, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        // Don't delay the first time        
        yield return source;

        while (true)
        {
            yield return source.DelaySubscription(dueTime, scheduler);
        }
    }

    public static IObservable<TSource> RetryAfterDelay<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan dueTime, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return RepeateInfinite(source, dueTime, scheduler).Catch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a text-book example for [Retry](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html#Retry).

```
public static IObservable<TSource> RetryAfterDelay<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan dueTime, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return RepeateInfinite(source, dueTime, scheduler).Retry();
}
```

Comment: Can't do a `Retry` on `IEnumerable<IObservable<TSource>>` only seems to support `Catch`