# Observable that retries only when a condition is met

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable

I want to resume a sequence only under certain condition.

I have this Observable:

```
Observable
    .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(SomeAsync))
    .Retry();
```

**The condition:** The observable should retry only when it receives an `CustomException` with a specific `ResultCode`.

Then, I've thought about this:

```
Observable
    .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(SomeAsync))
    .Catch<T, CustomException>(exception => ShouldRetry(exception) ? ____ : Observable.Throw<T>(exception));
```

But, I don't know what to put in the ____ part, when the Observable should retry itself. It seems like the definition contains the concept to be defined, something recursive.

How do I make this conditional retry?

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978523/write-an-rx-retryafter-extension-method) what you're after? `Observable.Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(SomeAsync))
  .RetryWithBackoffStrategy(
     retryCount: 4, 
     retryOnError: e => e is CustomException && e.ResultCode == 'my magic number'
  )`